# apply font and color on excel file created using ODBC drivers

Tags: excel, odbc, vba

I have created a MS excel file(.xls) file using ODBC drivers programmatically . It looks fine. Now i want to apply some font and color properties on text. But I don't know how could I do that. Is there any one who could help me out ? 
Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: You cannot do that using ODBC

Comment: Thanks Tim, Is there any other way to do this..?

Comment: Yes, you can use Excel to open the file an apply the formatting using automation. Most of that code you can get using the macro recorder plus a little manual tidying-up of the generated code.

Comment: It means I have to be dependent on MS excel or we can say office should be installed on system. right...?

Comment: Yes or you would need some other library capable of editing Excel files.

Answer (score -1):

There is a MS Excel library on www.codeproject.com by Yap Chun Wei.
I've used this library for many years with great success.
You can find the "BasicExcel" library on:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13852/BasicExcel-A-Class-to-Read-and-Write-to-Microsoft

Comment: Thnks Edwig, Does this library works on Images too..?